# How to remove a previously added script file in a Zend Framework controller?

Tags: php, javascript, zend-framework

Is it possible to remove a script that was previously added like this?

```
$this->view->headScript()->appendFile("/js/my.js");
```

The situation here is that in my `Bootstrap.php` several JavaScript files are appended like in the above example but in a particular controller I want one particular JavaScript file not to be loaded. Is there a way to remove it during the initiation of the controller?

I am looking for something like this.

```
$this->view->headScript()->removeFile("/js/my.js");
```

Comment: Just a guess but I think you can do it by manipulating the placeholder registry... `Zend_View_Helper_Placeholder_Registry::getRegistry()->getContainer("Zend_View_Helper_HeadScript")`

Comment: Thanks! I actually made it work this way. I will post the solution in a few moments.

Comment: Why do you ever need to remove this script? Probably the better practice would be to prevent appending it rather than removing.

Comment: I know, I know. And thank you for mentioning it. The reason is: it is a very large project. Many parts of the application rely on this script, so it's appended early in the bootstrapping cycle. In this branch of the application structure, though, it causes trouble and needed to be removed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**This works, but really isn't a good practice but rather for exceptional purposes. I recommend trying to not load the unwanted scripts in the first place.**

It is possible to remove scripts subsequently with a function like this one.

```
/**
 * Removes a previously appended script file.
 * 
 * @param string $src The source path of the script file.
 * @return boolean Returns TRUE, if the removal has been a success.
 */
public function removeScript($src) {
    $headScriptContainer = Zend_View_Helper_Placeholder_Registry::getRegistry()
            ->getContainer("Zend_View_Helper_HeadScript");
    $iter = $headScriptContainer->getIterator();
    $success = FALSE;
    foreach ($iter as $k => $value) {
        if(strpos($value->attributes["src"], $src) !== FALSE) {
            $iter->offsetUnset($k);
            $success = TRUE;
        }
    }
    Zend_View_Helper_Placeholder_Registry::getRegistry()
            ->setContainer("Zend_View_Helper_HeadScript",$headScriptContainer);
    return $success;
}
```

Note that the `strpos` function is used here. This will remove every script that has `$src` in its path. Of course you can change that to your needs.

Comment: What if I want to remove ALL the scripts?
I'm trying to use the headscript to append files to the end of page too. I tried removing the strpos if, but it offset the first one and then stops.

Comment: As I mentioned, the `strpos` call is for explanatory purposes only. You are free to replace it with any other expression that suits your use case. I think removing all the scripts should be a different question on stackoverflow. I really think it's not the same issue. You could ask and self-answer it. Again, people should be reminded that this isn't a good practice at all, and should be avoided if possible.

Answer (score 0):

It's an old question, but here is an alternative:
I used the [minifyHeadScript](https://github.com/bubba-h57/zf-helpers) and changed his helper adding this custom function:

```
/**
 * Removes all script file.
 *
 */
public function clearAllScripts(){
    $this->getContainer()->exchangeArray(array());
    $container = $this->getContainer();
    Zend_View_Helper_Placeholder_Registry::getRegistry()->setContainer("Zend_View_Helper_HeadScript", $container);
}
```